# Insert node as string but keep the instance of the node

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to insert a node, that is converted to a string, on a specific position.
the problem is that i want to keep or regain the instance of the node, but dont know how.

I hope some of you have a solution

**Note: I have to insert the element as string!**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="div">
    Here are <span class="span"></span> some text
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.div, .span {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
.span {
    min-width: 10px;
    max-width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var div = document.querySelector('.div');
var span = document.querySelector('.span');

// element to insert
var newElement = document.createElement('div');
newElement.innerHTML = 'Hallo!';

// convert to string
var converter = document.createElement('div');
converter.appendChild(newElement);

// insert element at the end of span
span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML + converter.innerHTML;

// get the instance of the node? to interact with it
newElement.style.color = '#00ff00';
```

Example: **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anro/pen/YqVjed)**

Comment: `span.innerHTML = '<div id="yourNodeId"></div>'; var yourNode = document.getElementById('yourNodeId');` ?

Comment: `newElment` and `span` are both still around, what the problem?

Comment: @Yoplaboom Sounds good, but the insertion can happen multiple times and I dont want to change some attributes or content of the node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote small function for test:

```
function makeNode(innerHTML){
    var node = document.createElement('div');
    node.id = 'unique_id';
    node.innerHTML = innerHTML;

    document.body.innerHTML += node.outerHTML;

    return document.getElementById('unique_id');
}
```

Create element, insert in body, and return it

```
var elm = makeNode('test div');
```

Apply some style

```
elm.style = 'color:red;';
```

Try it: https://jsfiddle.net/nv6gyLve/

Comment: Wrap down the node in a div, good solution. Thank you!

`return document.getElementById('unique_id').childNodes;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set styles before insert element to dom. Other way -getElementById or same functions

Comment: it is within a function and I want to return the node